# How to put a right arrow above a Latin letter?

Tags: display, unicode

I want to write: ⃗E, I tried to `C-x 8 <RET> COMBINING RIGHT ARROW ABOVE <RET> E` it is displaying in Emacs like:

[image: how Emacs displays ⃗E]

I want to use Unicode (without Tex).

## EDIT

in reply to Drew's comment:

What I want is to put the arrow above the letter something like this:

[image: What I want to write]

It appears in my browser correctly.

Yes, sure I can move the cursor past the arrow but before the E.

doing `C-u C-x =` for the first character gives:

```
             position: 45 of 49 (90%), column: 2
            character: ⃗ (displayed as ⃗) (codepoint 8407, #o20327, #x20d7)
    preferred charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
code point in charset: 0x20D7
               script: symbol
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: ^:Combining
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 20d7" or "C-x 8 RET COMBINING RIGHT ARROW ABOVE"
          buffer code: #xE2 #x83 #x97
            file code: #xE2 #x83 #x97 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    xft:-PfEd-Unifont-normal-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-d-0-iso10646-1 (#x20DA)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: COMBINING RIGHT ARROW ABOVE
  old-name: NON-SPACING RIGHT ARROW ABOVE
  general-category: Mn (Mark, Nonspacing)
  decomposition: (8407) ('⃗')

There are text properties here:
  fontified            t

[back]
```

And the next character (letter E) output is:

```
             position: 46 of 49 (92%), column: 2
            character: E (displayed as E) (codepoint 69, #o105, #x45)
    preferred charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x45
               script: latin
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, L:Left-to-right (strong), a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 45" or "C-x 8 RET LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E"
          buffer code: #x45
            file code: #x45 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    xft:-GOOG-Noto Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x28)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
  general-category: Lu (Letter, Uppercase)
  decomposition: (69) ('E')

There are text properties here:
  fontified            t

[back]
```

Comment: 1. It's not clear what is different between what you wanted to happen and what happened. Please clarify/elaborate. 2. What happens if you put the cursor just before the character(s) you get and you use `C-u C-x =`? What does Emacs tell you then about what that character is? 3. Can you move your cursor past the arrow but before the `E`? That would indicate that there are two characters present. If so, put your cursor there and do `C-u C-x =`. Try to provide as much info as you can about just what you want and what you get instead.

Answer (score 1):

Combining characters always combine with the character that comes before them, so put the `E` first. Note that in the output of `C-u C-x =` you pasted above, the arrow has combined with the space character that came before it.

Comment: If I type `E C-x 8 <RET> COMBINING RIGHT ARROW ABOVE <RET>` the arrow doesn't appear above the letter.

Comment: However, I found out that typing `C-x 8 <RET> VECTOR OR CROSS PRODUCT <RET> C-x 8 <RET> COMBINING RIGHT ARROW ABOVE <RET>` displays a cross product with a right arrow above it (as I wanted for letter E).